# Replace hash keys with new string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

**Company model**: There is aa attribute `name` and company `has_many users`.

**Users model**: User `belongs` to company.

**Query**:

After the query execution, below is my result.

```
users = {1360=>[#<User id: 2183, company_id: 1360, name: "XYS">, #<User id: 2184, company_id: 1360, name: "XYS1">], 1361=>[#<User id: 2185, company_id: 1361, name: "ABC">]}
```

In users object, there is one more column that is `company_name` which is fetch in query as alias, because I want only `company_name` not other attributes.

```
users = {1360=>[#<User id: 2183, company_id: 1360, name: "XYS", company_name="One">, #<User id: 2183, company_id: 1360, name: "XYS", company_name="One">], 1361=>[#<User id: 2185, company_id: 1361, name: "ABC", company_name="Two">]}
```

Here is the my desired output.
(Key would be company_name and its velue will be array of users info(name and id))

```
users = {"One"=>[["XYS", 2183], ["XYS1", 2184]], "Two"=>[["ABC", 2185]]}
```

How can I do that. Because when I try to replace the key(id) with name throughs an error

Comment: What is the error that you get when you replace key(id)? Also, from where do you get this: "One" and "Two"? in your desired result?

Comment: One and Two are the companies name. I am fetching the users in which I have fetch one more column that the `name`(as `company_name`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
users.map{  |_,array| [array.first.company_name, array.map{ |a| [a.name, a.id] }] }.to_h
```

Comment: There is `]` missing?

Comment: Technically, this is not "replacing the key", though :)

Comment: `v` is an `array`. How can we call `company_name` on `array`?

Comment: @PiotrKruczek - Still having a problem. If both companies have same name  (One) coincidentally. Then out put is wrong!

Comment: Then you need to change the expected output. Hashes **need** to have unique keys!